# Grails Tests loading fixture data multiple times when using named datasource

Tags: grails, datasource, integration-testing, duplicates, fixture

I'm working on a Grails plugin with it's own domain class.  My integration tests worked fine until I started using a named data source.  Now, when I run my tests the fixture data gets duplicated in the database with each call to `fixtureLoader.load()` in my tests.

Here is an example of my domain object, fixture, etc:

Program.groovy:

```
package mydomain

class Program {
  String name
  String code

  static mapping = {
    datasource 'myData'
  }
  String toString() {
    "$name ($code)"
  }
}
```

programData.groovy:

```
import mydomain.*
fixture {
  currentProg1(Program, name:'Program Name', code:'44')

}
```

My data source is configured like so:

```
    test {
    dataSource_myData {
        dbCreate = "create-drop"
        url = "jdbc:h2:mem:testDb;MVCC=TRUE;LOCK_TIMEOUT=10000"
    }
```

And my tests are like this:

```
package mydomain

import grails.plugin.spock.IntegrationSpec

class ProgramSpec extends IntegrationSpec {
def fixtureLoader

def "test current program list"() {
    given:
        def loader = fixtureLoader.load("programData")
    when:
        List results = Program.list()
    then:
        assert results.size() == 1          
}

    def "test toString"() {
    given:
        def loader = fixtureLoader.load("programData")
    when:
        def testCase = loader.currentProg1
    then:
        assert testCase.toString() == "Program Name (44)"
} 
}
```

When I run the tests I get:

```
Failure:  test current program list(com.sg.contract.guide.ProgramSpec)
Condition not satisfied:
results.size() == 1
|       |      |
|       2     false
[Program Name (44), Program Name (44)]
```

If I comment out the second test it works fine.  But running both tests causes the fixture data to get inserted into the DB twice.

If I change my data source and remove the named source (change `dataSource_myData` to `dataSource`) and remove the datasource configuration from mapping of my domain class it also works.

I don't know why having a named datasource causes fixture data to either get inserted twice or not get cleaned up after each test.  Any ideas?

Comment: I am having some problems trying/recreating your issue using fixtures, unable to recognize `domain` class in `spock` integration test? Isn't build-test-data a viable option for you? Which version of Grails are you using?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by build-test-data.  I'm using Grails 2.0.4

Comment: I meant [build-test-data](http://grails.org/plugin/build-test-data) plugin?

Comment: Well I kind of got it working.  I think I had a type-o when defining the datasource in my mapper (of my original code, not the stripped down version listed above).  If I run `test-app ProgramSpec` it works but when it runs with other tests I get duplicate data.  Seems like it isn't purging data from old tests before running new tests.

Comment: Great. I am not sure about `Spock` retaining the data across tests, but grails integration tests should not. If you still get that, then hail `tearDown()`. :)

Comment: Well, this is a puzzle.  If I use a non-default datasource the fixture loader loads duplicate data into the database each time a test calls fixtureLoader.load("programData")
But if I just use the default datasource it works fine.  I even duplicated the issue in a separate Grails project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug. I've created ticket, please vote for it http://jira.grails.org/browse/GPFIXTURES-28